# How to create ERD from Heroku PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, erd, beaver

I would like to create ERD from my Heroku PostgreSQL database? How can I generate ERD?
Is there any external tool that will help with this? Can you use Dbeaver for this?

Thanks,
Hema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) to create ERD from [Heroku Postgres](https://www.datensen.com/blog/data-modeling/heroku-postgres-and-er-diagrams/).